# Error in the Algorithm Design Manual?

Tags: algorithm-analysis

Take a look at this excerpt from the Algorithm Design Manual, 2nd Edition by Skiena.

[image]
[image]

I have circled the confusing bit. Basically, everything is understandable to me, until that part. How can $Increment([m+1/2])$ be rewritten as $Increment([m])$? Clearly, if m is an integer, then the algorithm will not treat $m+1/2$ as $m$ and return $m+1$. Instead, $Increment$ is going to go into the $else$ clause and return $m+1/2+1$, which is clearly not $m+1$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You should replace the image with text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can $Increment([m+1/2])$ be rewritten as $Increment([m])$?

Recall that $[x]$ means the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Since $m$ is integer, $m$ is the less than $m+0.5$ and $m+0.5 < m+1$. Thus the the greatest integer less than or equal to $m+0.5$ is $m$.

Comment: Where does it say that $[x]$ in $Increment$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$?

Comment: $[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. It is a standard definition, not specific to your problem.

Comment: Okay! That solves my confusion.

Comment: Nitpick: note that the textbook uses the $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ notation, which is less ambiguous than $[\cdot ]$. Only the OP used the latter notation.

Comment: @chi I don't see any ambiguity in both $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ and $[\cdot]$, both are well defined notations, though agree that textbook uses $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ instead of $[\cdot]$. They coincide when defined on the set of positive reals, though different on the set of negative reals.

Comment: Well, sometimes square brackets are used as parentheses, usually where there are already multiple nested parentheses, so using square brackets makes the formula easier to read. Still, I agree on both being standard notations. In the context of the textbook, there is no confusion.